# Defaulting to Angular UI-Router Nested View

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router

I am trying to open the state **`'profile.general'`** by default when I navigate to the parent state profile which loads the main template.

How do I activate the nested state for the ui-view when the /profile url is navigated to?

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/profile/general");

$stateProvider.state('profile', {
    url: '/profile',
    abtract: true,
    views: {
        "main": {
            controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/index.tpl.html'
        }
    }
}).state('profile.general', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-general.html'
    //controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
}).state('profile.security', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-security.html'
}).state('profile.social', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-social.html'
}).state('profile.privacy', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-privacy.html'
}).state('profile.payments', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-payments.html'
}).state('profile.restrictions', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-restrictions.html'
});
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="profile-views" ui-view></div>
```

Comment: for profile.general set the url to be `""` empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrLGrOfliqbSlGP3zAMM?p=preview)

These lines should help:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when("/profile", "/profile/general");
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/profile/general");
```

And we should give **`url`** to the general sub state:

```
.state('profile.general', {
    //url: '/register/details',
    url: '/general',
    templateUrl: 'src/app/profile/profile-general.html'
```

So, with these in place, we have **`.when`** redirection... which whenever user is targeting just the abstract state - does redirect to selected url.

Also, because we introduced the url for a child, we can use the **`.otherwise`** as the overall default state.

Other way how to do that, is to omit the url of one child *(just exactly one child)*:

*[How to: Set up a default/index child state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-set-up-a-defaultindex-child-state)*

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrLGrOfliqbSlGP3zAMM?p=preview)